# Auto Div width with img's inside

Tags: jquery, html, css

Working on a custom image slider set up as follows;

**HTML**

```
<div id="frameDiv">
    <div id="containerDiv">
        <img class="sliderImage" />
        <img class="sliderImage" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#frameDiv {
   height: 200px;
   width: 450px;
   overflow:hidden;
   white-space: normal;
}

#containerDiv {
   position: relative;
   height: 200px;
}

.sliderImage {
   max-height: 200px;
   min-height: 200px;
   min-width: 134px;
   margin-right: 7px;
   float:left;
}
```

I have the `#containerDiv` width set with `jQuery` right now and the Slider is working as expected, with the click of a button the slider slides over and more images are then displayed in view. However the images are now being added dynamically and each image width is not the same. So I would like to have the `#containerDiv` width automatically set according to how wide the images are in `CSS`. I have tried to set `float: left` and `display: inline-block` to the `.sliderImage` I've also tried to set `white-space: nowrap;` on `#containerDiv`. Nothing seems to work. All of the images get pushed down below each other to the next line when they need to be all on the same line and then they will be hidden with the overflow setting. Is there a way to do it without `JavaScript` or `jQuery`?

**Edit:** 
I took out the overflow:hidden on this jsfiddle so you can see how it wraps down.
http://jsfiddle.net/ut3o3pg3/

Comment: can you make some live example on jsfiddle or codepen -..... inline-block and white-space must do the trick

Comment: @Danko I just added the jsfiddle link. I took out the overflow in the CSS so you can see how it wraps down.

Comment: It seems as if the `#containerDiv` width is trying to be set to the width of the images but it gets stopped by the `#frameDiv`.

Comment: Like this one? http://jsfiddle.net/ut3o3pg3/1/ it force the elements to stay inline

Comment: Yes! like that one. That's what I was doing, but for some reason it's not working in my actual code. So now I have to figure out what is overriding it. If you make it an answer I will accept it since it does solve the problem.

Comment: Yep be sure to apply the property white-space on the parent not the imgs

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, add containerdiv img{ inside block add the width and height if the image} this should give it a fixed size if the image is smaller width and height is smaller than the properties in the div the image will be stretched and if larger the image will be shrunk.

Comment: I'm not trying to stretch the images to the width/height of the `#containerDiv`. I'm trying to have the `#containerDiv` width set to the total width of all the images inside.

Comment: Try adding a width to the container div

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: table;` to `#containerDiv` and `#frameDiv` to dynamically grow them based on their content.

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to `#containerDiv` and `display: inline-block;` to `.sliderImage` to force images to display inline.

Check it out here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ut3o3pg3/2/)